# Woocommerce webhook response 200 message The Rest API is unavailable

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

When woocommerce (webhook) send a success message (200) but the body contain the below

```
{
    "errors": {
        "rest_api_unavailable": [
            "The Rest API is unavailable."
        ]
    },
    "error_data": []
}
```

Has anyone happened this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a client's site that this is currently happening to and unfortunately I have no answer. It is happening with only WooCommerce activated and a default theme and is sporadic. Most of the time the error is sent, but occasionally it sends a correct payload. This is with using WP REST API Integration v2 or any version other than Legacy API v3. When using Legacy API v3, it always sends a payload instead of error. That may be a work-around, however, the payload is completely different with different field names and would require changing your endpoint to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional testing on the site I was experiencing this on and narrowed it down to define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true) being set in wp-config.php. If you have this set, try commenting it out. In my tests, the correct payload was sent every time after commenting this constant out. Also, on a completely different site that I configured the same exact webhook/endpoint on that had no issues, as soon as I set ALTERNATE_WP_CRON to true, it started sending rest_api_unavailable for the payload. Please refer to these links for additional information and bug report:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/26878
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/28363